# 1970s(?) science fiction movie - Mad scientist transplants brains from his victims into monstrous creatures

Tags: story-identification, b-movies

I saw this movie on TV back in the 80's. I believe, however that it was made most likely in the 70's based on it's film style.  The movie was in color.  The only parts I can really remember was at the end our heroes confronted there enemy (a mad scientist type) in his lair.  I believe his lair was in a volcano or perhaps a cave.  The "mad scientist" used his technology to either transplant brains from his victims into other creatures or perhaps just there consciousness. I can't remember.  At the end though one of his creations (if memory serves it was a woman who had been implanted into a gryphon like creature) attacks him allowing our heroes to escape.  Does this information sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: Well it sounds like one of a million TV takes on *The Island of Doctor Moreau*. It was frequently ripped off in 80s TV and film - is there anything else you can remember?

Comment: Wish I could remember more.  You never think of those things at the time. :)  Really the biggest plot element I can remember was woman being turned into the gryphon like creature.  I've wracked my brain but that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could this be "[Latitude Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude_Zero_(film))" (1969)?

The plot involves people being rescued and brought to a base in a mountain on an island by a submarine. Here is part of the plot synopsis from Wikipedia that describes the gryphon type creature and the brain transplants.

> Latitude Zero is a paradise hidden fifteen miles below the surface at
>   the intersection of the Equator and the International Date Line. Gold
>   is plentiful there and is used for protective clothing by the island's
>   newcomers, while those who arrived in the 19th century prefer to dress
>   as they are accustomed, as no one ages or dies. Diamonds are very
>   common and used only in industrial use.
>
> Dr. Malic, however, wishes to destroy the paradise of Latitude Zero,
>   and uses giant rats and anthropomorphic bats in addition to James
>   Bond-style devices against the undersea kingdom. Worst of all, after a
>   cruel experiment grafting the wings of an eagle to a lion, he removes
>   the brain of the unsuccessful Kuroi and places her brain in the
>   creature. This proves to be his undoing when, at a critical moment,
>   Kuroi turns against Malic as he prepares to fire an energy cannon at
>   the escaping visitors, causing their destruction.

You can see the 'gryphon' at 1:17 in the trailer and the part where he takes out the brain of the woman to put into the gryphon at 1:38. You also get glimpses of animal/human hybrids and the volcano.

Comment: Oh yes this is it LOL.  Wow this came out the year I was born LOL. Thanks tons.  Now I can scratch this title off my bucket list LOL.

Comment: Thanks much MrInfinity, this was driving me crazy too! It came out 1 year before I was born. It's actually like Island of Dr. Moreau and 20,000 Leagues Under the Sea combined.

Answer (score 6):

Could this be [The Twilight People](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069426/) from 1972?

This is the only "*Island of Dr. Moreau*" rip-off/tribute I can think of that had any flying type creature in it. It also has a scientist who is experimenting with animal/human hybrids, he has a lab in a mountain? or volcano and it takes place on an island.

Comment: Wow this did fit many of my criteria LOL but alas it is not the one.  I distinctly remember the woman into gryphon part.  I get the impression (from old memory anyway) that the movie I'm looking for is more scifi ish and less like Island of Dr. Moreau.  Man I wish I could remember more, but it was so long ago. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Wow. I really want to know what this is now! The only '70s movie with a gryphon I can think of is "The Golden Voyage of Sinbad".